# Safety of an organic solvent in a sealed pressure pot or vacuum chamber

Tags: solvents, vapor-pressure, plastics

I am trying to experiment and find ways I can reuse various types of thermoplastics at home for hobby use and have investigated various solubilities of them in solvents (room temp or otherwise) to experiment with recasting in molds. One common issue with a mixture containing PolyStyrene is similar to casting of thermoset resins, trapped air bubbles (or even trapped solvent bubbles)resulting in pitted castings. So I was considering if it was possible to either degas the mixture by use of a vacuum chamber  during or before casting in addition to or in lieu a pressure pot like with thermoset. But my chemistry knowledge is limited to say the least whether this is safe or not.

Would the vacuum pump simply need to have solvent resistant fittings and/or a brushless motor to prevent ignition of vacuumed solvent vapors given off by the mixture?(ventilation would obviously be present

Likewise for a pressure pot, I assume whatever solvent evaporation that occurs would only continue until the air is totally saturated and then no further evaporation would occur ? And would just need to ensure proper ventilation when releasing the pressure in the chamber to avoid vapor build up in the immediate area?

Potential solvents used for the PS include Acetone,Toluene,THF,D-Limonene, a mixture from a dual cure (UV cure or mekp catalyst)polyester thermoset resin containing styrene monomer, or just styrene monomer.

Thanks for your time. Haven't been able to find any answers like this anywhere on the Internet.
Feel free to point out my stupidity if this is a dumb line of questions.

Comment: You'll never get the solven out of the melt, unless you first precipitate the PS by adding e.g. water or methanol. Save yourself a lot of trouble, and just melt the bulk plastic you want to recycle.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to dissolve and reuse plastic as a hobby might not be a good idea.

There are considerable environmental, as well as safety, concerns. Releasing sizable amounts of organic solvents into the atmosphere, whether as effluent from the pump or just from evaporation, is against the law in many locales. There are contaminated locations such as [Solvent Savers](https://cumulis.epa.gov/supercpad/SiteProfiles/index.cfm?fuseaction=second.cleanup&id=0201687), a United State Superfund remediation site.

In addition, as you've mentioned, the solvents may be immediately toxic, and also present a fire hazard.

While wanting to recycle and reuse plastics is laudable, it should be done in a way that does not cause further harm. A large commercial operation might evaporate, condense and reuse solvent with an efficient [counter-current heat exchanger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countercurrent_exchange), you're unlikely to do so at home.